# How do we make sense of angles which take irrational measures such as $\sqrt 2 ^\circ$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, real-numbers

If you were asked to draw such an angle how would you do so? Would you take it to a limit? Can the degree measure take the value of all real numbers?

Comment: Do you mean **construct** rather than **draw**. Drawing an angle like this has the same issues as drawing a line of this length. But you can **construct** a line of this length.

Comment: @Mufasa I don't know the difference between the two, could you explain?

Comment: e.g. I could construct a right-angled triangle with each side of length 1. Then I know that its hypotenuse must be $\sqrt{2}$. However, I can only ever *approximately* draw a line of length $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I see. So how would you **construct** this angle?

Comment: I have never seen such a construction so do not know if that is possible or not - sorry :(

Comment: How do you draw an angle of $1^\circ$?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot **construct** this angle with the usual construction tools (straightedge and compasses). The reason behind this is that the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) tells us that the complex number $$\cos\sqrt 2^\circ +i\sin\sqrt 2^\circ=\zeta_{360}^{\sqrt 2}$$
(where $\zeta_{360}$ denotes a primitive $360$th root of unity) is transcendental.

Comment: Do you mean $\zeta_{360} = \exp(i \frac{2\pi}{360})$?

Answer (score 0):

Another answer addresses the question of why this angle can't be constructed by ruler and compass. However, you also asked what the angle *means*.

I presume you know what an angle $\pi/n$ means. That is, it's the angle which, if added $n$ times, gives you $\pi$. (Proving such an angle exists is of course another matter.) And it is then easy to see what $\frac{m}{n}\pi$ means.

To say what $\sqrt{2}$ degrees means, it's the only angle that is larger than $q$ degrees, but smaller than $r$ degrees, whenever $q$ and $r$ are rational numbers satisfying $q < \sqrt{2} < r$. Again, I'm not offering a proof that such an angle exists.

To place this in a larger perspective, the real problem is to establish a mapping $\phi$ from the set of real numbers to the set of all rotations about the origin in such a way that $\phi(\alpha)$ represents the counterclockwise rotation of angle $\alpha$. More specifically:

1. $\phi(\alpha)$ must be a rotation centred at the origin for all $\alpha$. (More explicitly, in case there is any doubt about what a rotation means: it's either the identical transformation or an isometry of the plane whose only fixed point is the origin.)
2. We must always have $\phi(\alpha + \beta) = \phi(\alpha) \circ \phi(\beta)$.
3. $\phi(360)$ must be the identical transformation.
4. Whenever $0 < \alpha < 180$, the rotation $\phi(\alpha)$ must take the point $(1,0)$ to a point in the top half-plane (i.e., the rotation is counterclockwise).

It turns out that there is exactly one way to assign a rotation $\phi(\alpha)$ to each number $\alpha$ in such a way that all four conditions are satisfied. Then $\phi(\sqrt{2})$ is the counterclockwise rotation with angle $(\sqrt{2})^{\circ}$.