# Can you construct a 1-radian wide angle?

Tags: geometry

I would like to construct a 1-radian wide angle, with traditional tools, without using a decimal approximation. I saw a thread on here that talked about constructing a sqrt(2) angle, but I don't know if that applies to all irrational numbers or not.

[How do we make sense of angles which take irrational measures such as $\sqrt 2 ^\circ$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098856/how-do-we-make-sense-of-angles-which-take-irrational-measures-such-as-sqrt-2)

Comment: My instinct says that this is equivalent to constructing $\pi$ which would mean no.

Comment: @StellaBiderman saw your comment at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207400/proof-of-continued-fraction-question   Thanks. That OP repeatedly asks very similar questions and then deletes.

Answer (score 3):

There is a field called the constructible numbers,, call it $E,$ a subfield of the real numbers, also a subfield of the algebraic numbers. Begin with the rational numbers. For every positive field element $x \in E$ we require that $ \sqrt x \in E$ as well. Some people write constructable with a letter 'a.' I can't see it.

An angle $\alpha$ is constructible with traditional tools if and only if $\sin \alpha \in E,$ or if $\cos \alpha \in E,$ or if $\tan \alpha \in E,$ the three conditions being equivalent.

However, $\sin 1$ is not in $E.$ This is an application of the Lindemann theorem, that $\sin 1$ is transcendental. See Theorem 9.11 in *Irrational Numbers* by Ivan Niven, page 131 in my edition.